# Scheduling pod on control plane

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod that requires deployment on the control plane node specifically.

i tried using the "NodeAffinity" to require an expressions match based on the node's labels:

[image]

problem is, I need to by compliant with multiple k8s distros, and those may differ in the label's key.
for example, in rancher the key is "node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane" (no '-' in control plane).

is there a way to dynamically construct the key / match based on a value's prefix instead of the whole string / provide a custom regex expression as the value / perform an "or" operator between the required expressions/ any other solution which would not require adding a custom label, or using an additional tool such as helm?

Comment: Can't you just label the node on which you want your Pod to run with a custom label? Notice also that to run on control planes you will probably need to use tolerations: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

Comment: If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.